# If statement evaluates to false despite being true

Tags: javascript, html, substring

## UPDATE

Issue is not with `e.key === " "` but with the inner `if` statement, to clarify. The inner `if` always returns false no matter what. The outer `if` is fine. So far, we think that this might be an issue with `.innerText`. It could be returning a different whitespace character at the end.

---

I think I might have found an internal bug with Javascript or something because this does not work. I'm trying to prevent the user from inserting multiple spaces in a row in a content editable div using Javascript. User should be allowed to enter one space at a time.

```
This is allowed

This    is    not
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```js
document.getElementById("div")
  .addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === " ") {
      const text = this.innerText,
        i = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;

      const chars = text.substring(i - 1, i + 1);
      if (chars.includes(" ")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true id=div></div>
```

The logic seems correct to me. The problem is that it doesn't work. I can insert as many spaces as I want to and the browser doesn't care. I have logged the variables using a debugger at each step and it has the expected value, but when `chars.includes(" ")` is evaluated, the `if` statement always evaluates to `false` for some reason even though `chars` contains a  (space). Am i doing something wrong? please help.

Comment: Some basic debugging skills could have saved your time :). If this was truly due to bug in JS, that would be end of the (programming) world.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log("e.key is [" + e.key + "]");` at the top of your event handler?

Comment: @NikhilVartak really? Ok, so I changed it to `e.key === 32` and it still doesn't work. What else is wrong here?

Comment: @Pointy yes. It prints a space (like this `" "`) when I press the space bar. That's why I used `e.key === " "`

Comment: @NikhilVartak any luck my man?

Comment: @YangK see my answer.

Comment: when you use `const chars = text.substring(i - 1, i + 1)` it could be other whitespace other than space! Check for example [http://www.adamkoch.com/2009/07/25/white-space-and-character-160/]

Comment: @A.Akram link 404s. care to elaborate please?

Comment: @YangK i did not downvote (just fYI) but I think you should add *update* section in original content to state that issue is with *includes* and not with *key*. Because `e.key === ' '` works for sure and problem is with inner `if`. Initially we all focused on something that really was not a problem.

Comment: @NikhilVartak will do. thanks for the help mate. really appreciate it :)

Comment: In short if you try to `/\s$/.test(chars)` instead of `chars.includes(" ")` It should work!

Comment: @A.Akram that seems to work in every browser except ff. any idea why? really weird behavior in ff. thanks for the help btw

Comment: contenteditable behave differently in different browser. I think it was due to the fact that FF adds <br/> at the end of the div!

Comment: @A.Akram any idea on how i can look for that. i tried removing it by removing newline chars but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It might be a lot simpler to forget about checking the just-typed character, handle "keypress" instead of "keydown", and just filter repeated spaces out of all the text nodes in the element.

Comment: @YangK I have updated the answer again with a non-deprecated approach. Check it in non-chrome browsers. You can skip to the code snippet directly if you want to see if it works first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how contenteditable elements work, spaces you type are non-breaking spaces (ASCII 160) instead of normal spaces (ASCII 32). HTML collapses multiple spaces to one by default so spaces must be non-breaking inside the contenteditable, otherwise you wouldn't see more than one when typing multiple spaces.

You'll have to check for a non-breaking space specifically:

```js
document.getElementById("div")
  .addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === " ") {
      const text = this.innerText,
        i = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;

      const chars = text.substring(i - 1, i + 1);
      if (chars.includes( String.fromCharCode(160) )) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true id=div></div>
```

You might also want to check for normal spaces as well because I'm not sure if this behavior is consistent among browsers.

Comment: thanks mate for the help. this works in almost every browser except ff. any idea why it doesn't work in ff? thanks again for being of so much help

Comment: Firefox inserts a line break at the end of the element so `chars` is always a newline (10). You can debug this yourself if you add `console.log(chars.charCodeAt(0))` to the code.

Comment: that's what I tried actually. If i do that then I can even add one space. It prevents me from adding any spaces at all.

Comment: How does adding a console.log statement change how it behaves? Or do you mean that you added a check for a newline? Of course that won't work, like I said Firefox *always* inserts a linebreak at the end. You'll have to first remove the linebreak and then check the last character.

Comment: Of course, users can always just type a letter, move back with arrow keys and then type as many spaces as they want. Or copy-paste text that contains spaces. The entire approach is wrong if you want to prevent multiple spaces in all situations.

Comment: its not true that users can use the arrow keys to go back. you can try that with your own answer and it doesn't work. Also i have other measures that i'm taking to prevent the multiple spaces on paste so my approach isn't wrong. I have just pasted part of the code to be more clear and concise with my question. that doesn't make my whole question wrong. :) additionally, in reference to your earlier comment, yes I tmeant that i tried removing the \n character and then checking for a space in firefox but that still doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

**First,** add a `keydown` listener to check what the last key pressed was like this:

```
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

});
```

**Second,** Within that listener function, add another function, say `stop()` that has all the codes that you want to run (e.g. `preventDefault()`, `return false`, etc) if someone is trying to add two consecutive spaces like this:

```
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

    function stop() {
       alert("two whitespaces detected");
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }

});
```

**Third,** add an if statement inside the listener to check if the key last pressed was `space` like this:

```
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

    function stop() {
       alert("two whitespaces detected");
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }

    if (e.code == "Space" || e.key == " ") {

    }
});
```

**Fourth,** assign the value of whatever has been typed on the div to a variable, say `content` as a string and also assigned another variable, say `prevVal` to the last character of the `content` string like this:

```
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {


   function stop() {
       alert("two whitespaces detected");
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
   }

   if (e.code == "Space" || e.key == " ") {
       var divContent = e.target;
       var content = divContent.innerText;
       var prevVal = content.substr(content.length - 1);
   }
```

});

**Lastly,** you can either use another `if statement` to check if the last key pressed is a white-space or not by comparing it to the assigned variable `prevVal` above and if it is, run the stop() function that we wrote earlier like this:

```
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
       function stop() {
           alert("two whitespaces detected");
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
       }

       if (e.code == "Space" || e.key == " ") {
           var divContent = e.target;
           var content = divContent.innerText;
           var prevVal = content.substr(content.length - 1);

         if (prevVal.trim() === '') {
             stop();
         } else {
             console.log("nevermind");
         }
       }
});
```

---

Check the **code snippet below** or go to this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/agev2ro5/86/)** to see the above code in action:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");

div.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
   function stop() {
       alert("two whitespaces detected");
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
   }
   
   if (e.code == "Space" || e.key == " ") {
       var divContent = e.target;
       var content = divContent.innerText;
       var prevVal = content.substr(content.length - 1);
       
     if (prevVal.trim() === '') {
         stop();
     } else {
         console.log("nevermind");
     }
   }
});
```

```css
#div {border: 1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185764/discussion-on-answer-by-andrewl-if-statement-evaluates-to-false-despite-being-tr).

Comment: still doesn't work mate. it runs an error and i can keep adding spaces no matter what

Comment: also, please try all your code without the `alert` statement. that makes a big difference

Comment: @YangK That's weird. Did the error happened when you tried adding more than one whitespace in the jsfiddle or the code snippet above or did the error happened in your local files?

Comment: `e.path[0]` is undefined. in the snippet abovve

Comment: @YangK Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/agev2ro5/57/ without the alert and it seems to be working fine for me. i cant add more than one whitespace consecutively.

Comment: @BhargavRao Can you please help us out and check the code snippet above to see if it returns `e.path[0] is undefined` or not for you. It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: `stop()` doesn't even get called mate

Comment: @BhargavRao is a mod, i think. he was just helping with moving the discussion to the chat.bhargav if you see this, neevu hegidira?

Comment: I'm literally trying out both the jsfiddle and the code snippet right now and both are working fine. It makes no sense. Let @BhargavRao or someone who sees this check the fiddles out and confirm if it is working or not.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have no idea about JavaScript and can't help you out. However, I really prefer if you guys use chat instead of talking in the comments. It is hard to manage comment threads once they go beyond 30~35 comments

Comment: @BhargavRao this is the last comment and i'll move this to the chat. Andrew, your solution works in no browser except chrome. in every other browser, `e.path[0]` is undefined

Comment: @BhargavRao Apologies. Will do that. But can you just type any random text in the code snippet box and then add two whitespaces. Did you get an alert as well as prevented from typing the extra space?

Comment: @YangK Wait so you're saying it works in chrome however?

Comment: You should have told me that earlier. Let me fix the code.

Comment: @AndrewL yes, chrome in fact is the only browser it works in. checking edge right now but pretty sure it won't work there either

Comment: Yes, it works in Chrome. Now please use the chat room, else I would have to lock the post for too many comments.

Comment: @AndrewL `e.keyCode` is depracated

Comment: also which jsfiddle are you referring ti @AndrewL

Comment: @AndrewL also, your code right now only allows one space in total

Answer (score 1):

ok, you can't put 2 spaces anywhere

edit: works in chrome, ff, edge

```js
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.code === 'Space' || e.key === ' ') {
    const node = window.getSelection();
    const text = node.anchorNode.textContent;
    const cur = node.anchorOffset;
    const front = text[cur - 1];
    const back = text[cur];
    const reg = /\s/;
    if (reg.test(front) || reg.test(back)) e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update**
This implementation ignores newline characters and will cause bugs if they are added by the user (In the app i'm implementing, I don't allow the user to add any newline characters, so this implementation works). For a full implementation please have a look at @WASD 's answer.

**Update TLDR**: Implementation works on Firefox, Edge, Safari, Chrome, and Opera when 'Enter' key is not allowed.

---

After some playing around, I finally figured out a solution. In firefox, `.innerText` is very buggy. Therefore, we need to use `.textContent` instead which works well for all browsers. If we use `.textContent`, in all browsers except Firefox, when the user presses the spacebar, a character that looks like a space is added to the content, but IT IS NOT a space. It's actually a different character which is the `ASCII` character `160`. In Firefox, the normal `ASCII` character `32` is used for the space. Now that we have this information, we can get started on solving the problem. Here is a cross-browser implementation that works.

```js
document.getElementById("div")
        .addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === " ") {
      const text = this.textContent,
            i = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;

      const chars = text.substring(i - 1, i + 1);
      if (chars.includes(" ") || 
          chars.includes(String.fromCharCode(160))) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div style="border: 2px solid black;" contenteditable=true id=div></div>
```

Firstly, we use `.textContent` instead of `.innerText`. Additionally, in the `if` statement, we check if the text in the contenteditable `div` includes the conventional `space` char (`ASCII 32`) and we also check if it includes the `ASCII 160` which is used by every browser except FF. If the text includes the 160 or 32 char, then we need to `preventDefault()` and stop the user from adding multiple space characters consecutively.

Comment: came back because my mind wasn't settled cuz I didn't provide how it broke, now I tried again and couldn't do it wth

Comment: Ok found it, press a a space space enter space space , and there you have it, 2 spaces. There must be one more tho where you won't be able to add a space where it's supposed to work.

I found a solution tho, check my answer

Comment: @WASD thanks for your kind help. I really appreciate it. In the app I'm making, I don't need to worry about users adding newline chars, because I have completely disabled that in my content editable div. I answered my own question while keeping that in mind so I didn't address that bug you're pointing out. However, I now realize that your implementation answers the question much better than mine in a general way that will be useful to the next person using it as they might not disable newline characters in their content editable div like I did. Will accept your answer over mine. Thanks again.

Comment: @WASD upvoted and accepted. thanks a lot for coming back and solving the underlying problem. :)